# How to prove that this ODE has no real solutions?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We are asked to show that
$$\left|\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right|+\left|y\right| +1=0$$
has no real solutions.

---

My proposed solution: Of course, $\left|\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right|$ and $\left|y\right|$ are non-negatives and 1 is positive. So, sum of all three of them can't be equal to zero (must be positive here) for any function $y=f(x)$.

---

My question: Is this argument strong enough to show that the ODE has no real solutions?

Comment: Yes. LHS is clearly $\ge 1$

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your arguments are fine.

$\left|\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right|+\left|y\right| +1 \ge 1 >0.$

Hence we never have

$\left|\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right|+\left|y\right| +1=0$.